# Can't change elementary OS resolution on Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox

I installed elementary OS on Virtual Box. My prime OS is Windows 8.1. So after the installation I tried to change the resolution, but the only resolution available was 640x480. I tried to insert Guest addition, but it gives me this error. [image: This Error]

Comment: See [my answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/2725/2708)  in ^ post, exactly answer your Q. =)

Comment: Yes, thank you ! Very good guide, easy and simple. It worked flawlessly.

Comment: If worked, I recommend you to close as duplicate = ) @BlackSova

Answer (score 0):

Solved this just now on a Mac host in Virtualbox 5.0.8 by
in terminal for host:
VBoxManage setextradata global GUI/MaxGuestResolution any

and then in terminal for guest:  all the steps set out at
 [install-virtualbox-guest-additions-elementary-os](http://www.binarytides.com/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-elementary-os-luna/).

required some small experience with using the terminal, reading the text to understand what it was telling me to do about installing dependencies and removing unneeded or broken things.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

got used a lot, probably more than necessary.

Once I did that, screen sizes are available.

Then I went to the Files window and tried to change from icons to list and everything froze and I had to power cycle the VM, but it seems to still work after restarting it.