# How to share files and folders between host and guest in virtual box?

Tags: virtualbox

I am using elementary OS freya.

How to share files and folders between host and guest in virtual box ?

elementary OS- Host / elementary OS- Guest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instructions:

1. Install *Guest Additions* in virtual box.

   see [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/903/how-do-you-install-virtualbox-extensions-in-elementary-os/2725#2725) for Installation.
2. Install extension pack. Download [link](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.8/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.0.8-103449.vbox-extpack). After installation, *right-click* on downloaded file and select *open with Oracle VM virtual box*

   [image: Imgur]

3.Create a folder in **host**

I  will create a folder `SHARE` in `home` directory.

4. Goto VirtualBox **settings**--> **shared folders** --> *Adds new shared folder* ( folder sign with green +)

   [image: Imgur]

**Note**: If the Virtual Machine already running, you will have `make permanent` option. If the Virtual Machine is not running already you will have only other two options. (I mentioned this point to avoid confusion, like, *how his VBox has `make permanent` option* o_O )

5. Now open Virtual Machine (guest) then open terminal and run the command:

   ```
   sudo adduser [user_name] vboxsf
   sudo reboot
   ```

*Example* : `sudo adduser ravan vboxsf`

6. Now open *files* --> *file system* --> *media*

   There you will have your `SHARE` folder.

   [image: Imgur]